# Flutter - OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-file

In my Flutter Application, I have some data to use. Initially, I created a variable and stored this data in it, but but it became too large and hindered the code's readability. Then, I thought about creating a .json file and putting this JSON data inside a variable in the file where I need to access this data. However, I tried a few approaches, and in all of them, I encountered this error: 'OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2', stating that it couldn't find the file."

This is my code:

```
Future<String> get _localPath async {
    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

    return directory.path;
  }

  Future<File> get _localFile async {
    final path = await _localPath;
    return File('$path/lib/layers/equipment_care.json');
  }

  Future<String> readCounter() async {
    try {
      final file = await _localFile;

      // Read the file
      final contents = await file.readAsString();

      return contents.toString();
    } catch (e) {
      // If encountering an error, return 0
      return "";
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    readCounter().then((value) {
      print(value);
    });
    return Container(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: _appBar(),
        body: _body(),
      ),
    );
  }
```

In the image below, is possible to see the json file path (equipment_care.json), the path of the dart file (know_more_equipment_screen.dart) and the file of flutter project.
The path of directory.path returns this:

```
/data/user/0/(censored)/app_flutter
```

and the path of the File('$path/lib/layers/equipment_care.json') is

```
/data/user/0/(censored)/app_flutter/lib/layers/equipment_care.json
```

[image]

It's this last link that it's looking for, and it's not returning anything. I would really like to know why it's not finding the file and what I might have done wrong so I can fix it. Could someone please help?

Note: The 'censored' in the address is because I can't show that specific part of the path, but it's the same in all cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was need to add json file path in assets inside pubspeck.yaml:

```
assets:
   - lib/layers/equipment_care.json
```

and to get json data, I did this:

```
    Map dataEquipment = {};

    void initState(){
        readCounter().then((value) {
          dataEquipment = json.decode(value);
        });
        super.initState();
      }
    
      Future<String> readCounter() async {
        try {
          String jsonString = await rootBundle.loadString('lib/layers/equipment_care.json');
          return jsonString;
    
        } catch (e) {
          return "";
        }
      }
```

after to do this changes, I was able to get data from json file

Answer (score -1):

try adding the path_provider package:

```
dependencies:
  path_provider: ^2.0.15
```

let me know if you solve the problem or not

Comment: Mouaad, thanks for the answer! I already had this package in my pubspeck yaml.
I managed to solve the problem, I replied here the changes that I needed to make, if you want to see!

Comment: alright, i thought that you already added the file to your assets in pubspeck.yaml, I'm glade that you managed to solve it